# Unable to locate asset entry

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting some weird error. I have my project on my GitHub repository, and when I push it to another computer, I started to get this error. And as you can see, already have it in fonts folder

[image]

And to be clear, I'm gonna share my pubspec.yaml too, because it's right. I've tried - flutter - clean, restart my computer, change assets folder, I don't know why, because the images assets are loading correctly on app, just the fonts gettin' this error. :c

[image]

EDIT 1 - Still can't use fonts, images assets still loading normal
EDIT 2 - Noqw it's working, for some reason when pull from Github repository, extension name to to uppercase, like "ARIAL.TTF", just renamed it to "ARIAL.ttf" and everything is working, thanks guys

[image]

Comment: check fonts path. it should be `assets/fonts/GOTHAM-BOLD.ttf`

Comment: I'm using in this way, but still got the error, Error: unable to locate asset entry in pubspec.yaml: "assets/fonts/GOTHAM-BOLD.ttf".

Comment: close the app in the simulator by pressing stop. Then restart the app by clicking on Run.

Comment: Already did it, also restared my computer, vs code, and still gettin the error.

Comment: please share the new error message screenshots

Comment: now it's working, for some reason when i push from github, extesion names recive uppercame, just changed,

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide a path of font asset correctly. Add `assets` to your path.

**Solution:**

```
fonts:
  family: Gotham
  fonts:
    - assets: assets/fonts/GOTHAM-BOLD.ttf
```

Comment: Still can't use fonts, Error: unable to locate asset entry in pubspec.yaml: "assets/fonts/GOTHAM-BOLD.ttf".

Comment: Have you re-build the application after made changes?

Comment: I even can make a build, when i press on run, it return this error, i've tried flutter clean too

Comment: Please move the `fonts` declaration below the `assets` declaration. And then let me know

Comment: now it's working, for some reason when i push from github, extesion names recive uppercame, just changed,